# Disabling Hyper-V on boot Win10?

Tags: startup, hyper-v

I saw in some post that enabling Hyper-V could improve emulator performance, so during my Windows 10 Session I installed and activated it from the services thingy (sorry, it's just, I'm a little freaked out). After installing it told me to reboot, so I did, and then I'm stuck at infinite loop restart, always trying to repair windows. I can't get back to previous restore, I can't enter safe mode, and I can't reinstall windows. Only way seems to plug in a USB and fresh install; I'd like to avoid that. Any tips on disabling the feature I just installed without being able to start up Windows?

Comment: Did you make sure to turn on Hardware Virtualization Support in the BIOS settings?  If not, you should be able to get to the BIOS settings when first booting and enable that setting.

Comment: Sure, virtualization on BIOS is on. It is "Intel Virtualization Technology" right? Still no luck :/

Comment: Ok, have you tried turning it off to see if it boots?

Comment: That I did too, still wants to repair with no sucess. Neither options let me boot